# AWStats not showing anymore Referrers / Keywords /keyphrases

Tags: ubuntu, perl, apache2, awstats

Me and my colleagues are struggling to find a solution over a strange problem with AWStats. Some months ago, we moved a production environment from a CentOS to an Ubuntu 14.04. Since then, the Referrers sections  is not showing anymore browsers / external pages access and the Search Keywords and Search Keyphrases sections are empty. Do you have any clue about what could be causing this?
Here are our current software versions:

- Ubuntu 14.04 kernel 3.13.0-108-generic
- Apache2: 2.4.10
- Perl: 5.18.2
- Awstats: 6.6 build 1.887

### Apache2 log configurations:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" 
combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
```

### Awstats log configurations:

```
LogFile="/var/log/apache2/access.log"
LogFormat=1``LogType=W`
LogSeparator=" "
```

### extract from logs:

```
109.239.235.240 - - [31/Aug/2017:12:52:19 +0200] "GET /box-office-2/ HTTP/1.1" 200 18589 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36"
109.239.235.240 - - [31/Aug/2017:12:52:19 +0200] "GET /flash-news/ HTTP/1.1" 200 18895 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0"
109.239.235.240 - - [31/Aug/2017:12:52:19 +0200] "GET /eventi/venezia/ HTTP/1.1" 200 19960 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36"
109.239.235.240 - - [31/Aug/2017:12:52:19 +0200] "GET /eventi/gioco-lotto/ HTTP/1.1" 200 19720 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36"
109.239.235.240 - - [31/Aug/2017:12:52:19 +0200] "GET /altri-articoli/ HTTP/1.1" 200 19705 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0"
109.239.235.240 - - [31/Aug/2017:12:52:19 +0200] "GET /eventi/torino-festival/ HTTP/1.1" 200 19571 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0"`
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you need more info please ask.

Comment: Please show one of the following: 1) Extract of log file from old and new server. 2) Log file format configuration from old and new server. 3) Log format configuration on Apache, AWStats and extract from log file from the new server.

Comment: Your Apache log does not show referral information for some reason. Do you have something else with Apache that is dealing with serving web pages?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen like what, for example? We  have Wordpress on it, but it was there  since before the  migration.

Comment: I mean a load balancer or something.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen I'm not really sure about that because we're using a web hosting (Aruba)

Comment: Time to talk to your hosting provider.  Something upstream of Apache is stripping Referer headers, by the look of it.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to changes in search engine URL's.  Nothing to do with your actions.

> I fear this is not an AWStats problem. Some time ago I observed that most UA strings originating from search engines do not provide the query information any more. Look at the example you provided. It contains ... &q=& ... Google used to provide the query information after the "q=". Now this is only an empty string as the "&" starts the next parameter. So AWStats does not have the information to calculate keywords and keyphrases.

https://sourceforge.net/p/awstats/discussion/43428/thread/16e71c5b/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Since links may become invalid in the future, please quote the essential part in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Google has stopped giving away searched keywords info. Blame it to Google and not AWStats. It shows what it gets.